# Fragment in fragment do not refresh

Tags: android, fragment

this is my app (with fragments):
On the left side there is a ListView where you can choose.
If you selected one the right side load a fragment and add Tabs to the ActionBar.
There is the code for that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class SpieleUndTabelleFragment extends SherlockFragment
{       
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ActionBar bar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(getSherlockActivity());
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.removeAllTabs();
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Alle Spiele"), Spiele.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tabelle"), Tabelle.class, null);

        return mViewPager;
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo
        {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager)
        {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
        {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeAllTabs()
        {
            mActionBar.removeAllTabs();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag)
                {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

The Spiele and Tabelle-Class load into the fragments and runs like i want.
If i click of one category (of the left fragment) the right Tabs with Spiele and Tabelle-Calss loads and run.
But if i click a second time of a other category on the left side the tabs in actionbar are removed and new one load. But there is my problem.
Tabelle and Spiele-Tabs doesnt load again! I have always a blank page! because the to classes doesnt load again...

Here is the code which i refresh the right fragment with the tabs:

```
SpieleUndTabelleFragment fragment = new SpieleUndTabelleFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.commit();
```

Can anybody help me?!
Thank you!

---------------- ***updated:*** ---------------------

i use `getFragmetManager()` because i have a `setOnItemListener()` with inner-class. If i want to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` eclipse say it doestnt support it.
here is the code from `onCreateView()` from the class:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waehle_mannschaft, container, false);

    ListView myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    myList.setDivider(null);

    final String[] listContent = {"News", "Gästebuch", "Herren 1", "Herren 2", "Herren 3", "Damen 1", "Damen 2", "männl. A", "männl. B1", "männl. B2", "männl. C", "männl. D", "E-Jugend"}; 

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    final View v2 = view;
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(v2.getContext(), listContent[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(twoPanels)
            {                   
                SpieleUndTabelleFragment fragment = new SpieleUndTabelleFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v2.getContext(), SpieleUndTabelleActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
```

Spiele is blank at this time. Tabelle show a basic tabelle. Like the image:
[image]
and i say it again. the first time i choose a item on the left fragment it do what i want. but if click a second time the # Verein + 0 - Punkte goes away and it is a blank page...beacuse tabelle dont load again...

Comment: Sure you are using `getFragmentManager()`? Shouldn't compile. Should be `getSupportFragmentManager()`. What's happening in `Spiele` and `Tabelle`? `SpieleUndTabelleFragment` is fine. Also please add the basics of your `SherlockListFragment` subclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `onCreateView` doesnt get called the second time you load it because it is already created.

Move the code for attaching the fragment

to `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: yes, that's it!
But I solved the problem in which I have taken from the FragmentPageAdapter to FragmentStatePageAdapter.

Thanks for help

Comment: if the answer is correct it would  be nice to accept it as the valid answer. this would also improve your accept rating and make other more likely to help you. ;-)

Comment: Change `FragmentPageAdapter` to `FragmentStatePageAdapter` also solves my problem, thank you for the tip!