# Refreshing a fragment on listview item click

Tags: java, android

I'm new to fragments and have been trying to solve this for days. I am trying to have my fragments update on a listview click, and is extremely similar to this:
[Fragment in fragment do not refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808046/fragment-in-fragment-do-not-refresh)
where there is both a listview on the left and a tabbed ui on the right. Here is one of my fragments:

```
public static class DescriptionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_description, container, false);

        text = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description));

        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(description_text));


        return rootView;
    }
```

how can i call this fragment (from inside the main activity) so onCreateView is renewed and the textview 'text' is updated? Any help is greatly appreciated

NOTE: the listview is not a fragment, just a seperate layout file for a tablet. My only fragments (such as DescriptionFragment) are for the tabs

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/access-view-inside-fragment-from.html. might help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are tying to show listview and on click of listitem, value should be update:

> How can I call this fragement (from inside the main activity) so onCreateView is renewed and the textview 'text' is updated?

To call fragment inside main activity, you have to define fragment in side main xml file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<fragment
android:id="@+id/frag_series"
android:layout_width="200dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
class="com.example.demo_fragment.MyListFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now extends Listframent instead and code to fill listview data later fire click event like below

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
DetailFragment frag = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_capt);
if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
frag.setText(getCapt(item));
}
}
```

and then check condition and update your vaules, like below:

```
private String getCapt(String ship) {
if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("android")) {
return "Andy Rubin";
}
if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("IOS")) {
return "Steve Jobs";
}
return "???";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i've put a fragment in my xml file but this in my listview: "DescriptionFragment frag = (DescriptionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_description);" gives me the error Cannot cast from Fragment to kick_activity.DescriptionFragment

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can call your fragment.

```
DescriptionFragment  descriptionFragment = (DescriptionFragment ) 
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a listener `Interface` something like this

```
public interface FragmentTransactionListener {
    public void updateFragment(/*some attributes*/);
}
```

You then have to implement the interface on your `Fragment` and override the `updateFragment` method. In this method you can add your code that will execute in the `Fragment` when your list item is clicked. Something like this

```
public static class DescriptionFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentTransactionListener {

...

    @Override
    public void updateFragment(/*some attributes*/) {
        //do some stuff
    }

...
```

When your fragment is created in your `FragmentActivity` get a instance of this listener and call it when your list item is clicked. Something similar to this code

```
FragmentTransactionListener listener = instance of your fragment;

//in your list item you then call this
listener.updateFragment(/*some attributes*/);
```

hope this helps